# Use Named range in a COUNTIFS

Tags: excel, vba

i'm in trouble with a countifs formula that needs to be use with named range (dynamic range).

So i've set my ranges with the first row and last used row and it apparently works.
but when i want to use these named range in my count if, then it doesnt work. 
Just to help you to understand, the countif without vba is looking like this : 
=NB.SI.ENS($F$28:$F$400;E16;$H$28:$H$400;"*Topé*")

**and with VBA :**

```
   Dim NoPremièreLigne As Long
  Dim NoDernièreLigne As Long
  Dim maplage2 As string
  Dim maplage3 As string


NoPremièreLigne = 28
NoDernièreLigne = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set maplage2 = "H" & NoPremièreLigne & ":" & "H" & NoDernièreLigne
Set maplage3 = "F" & NoPremièreLigne & ":" & "F" & NoDernièreLigne


    Range("F16").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=COUNTIFS(" & maplage3 & ",E16," & maplage2 & ",""Topé"")"
```

and this doesnt work, i dont have a error message but in the cell i have a #name

Thanks a lot if you have any idea about the problem....

Jm

Comment: Remove all blank spaces.  Or try with `"=COUNTIFS(" & maplage3.Address & ",E16," & maplage2.Address; " &,""*Topé*"")"`

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns - looks like misplaced quote and ampersand with extra semi-colon.

Comment: Hello, i tried your codes but it didnt work. so i changed a bit my code to get a string and now, i have the proper value in the cell BUT, i have still a #NAME error as i have ' in the formula : =NB.SI.ENS('F28':'F338';'E16';'H28':'H338';"Topé")   and the property adress returns a "invalid qualifier" mistake

Comment: in fact, i also tried to do it by using range (plage2/3 as range) etc and to use the adress property and i got a 1004 code error....

Comment: ok, ive sold my problem by doing : Range("F16") = _
      "=COUNTIFS(" & maplage3.Address & ",E16," & maplage2.Address & ",""Topé"")"       instead of     
        Range("F16").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
      "=COUNTIFS(" & maplage3.Address & ",E16," & maplage2.Address & ",""Topé"")"

Comment: It isn't recomannded to use `.Select` in this case, you should assign values or formulae directly.The correct way to assign a formula would be therefore `Range("F16").Formula = ...`, if you don't use the special rows/columns syntax as in `.FormulaR1C1`. If you omit this property, Excel has to devine what kind of data you want to assign. BTW you should use a fully qualified reference to your worksheet as well to avoid issues.

Comment: @Jeeped You're right. I'm sleepy lol, but i saw you posted the right one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Apply some basic string concatenation and use the range addresses.

```
Range("F16").Formula = _
  "=COUNTIFS(" & maplage3.address & ", E16, " & maplage2.address & ", ""*Topé*"")"
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering, but the property .adress doesnt work for me (explanations in message above)

Comment: I cannot explain how you are getting extra single quotes wrapping your range addresses. Nor can I explain why your range addresses are not absolute references.